# C++ for loop skips cin.get()

Tags: c++, for-loop, cin

In this for loop the cin.get(); is being skipped every other time. I have no idea why it is being skipped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
for(Pointer = StartPointer; Pointer < EndPointer; Pointer += MemInfo.RegionSize)
{

    VirtualQueryEx(hProc, (LPCVOID)(Pointer), &MemInfo, sizeof(MemInfo));
    cout << "MemInfo AllocationBase: " << MemInfo.AllocationBase << endl;
    cout << "MemInfo AllocationProtect: " << MemInfo.AllocationProtect << endl;
    cout << "MemInfo BaseAddress: " << MemInfo.BaseAddress << endl;
    cout << "MemInfo Protect: " << MemInfo.Protect << endl;
    cout << "MemInfo RegoinSize: " << MemInfo.RegionSize << endl;
    cout << "MemInfo State: " << MemInfo.State << endl;
    cout << "MemInfo Type: " << MemInfo.Type << endl;
    cout << "MemInfo Size: " << sizeof(MemInfo) << endl;
    cout << "Starter pointer is: " << StartPointer << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Example output between cin.get();

```
MemInfo AllocationBase: 00000000
MemInfo AllocationProtect: 0
MemInfo BaseAddress: 00000000
MemInfo Protect: 1
MemInfo RegoinSize: 65536
MemInfo State: 65536
MemInfo Type: 0
MemInfo Size: 28
Starter pointer is: 0
MemInfo AllocationBase: 00010000
MemInfo AllocationProtect: 4
MemInfo BaseAddress: 00010000
MemInfo Protect: 4
MemInfo RegoinSize: 65536
MemInfo State: 4096
MemInfo Type: 262144
MemInfo Size: 28
Starter pointer is: 0
```

Comment: Every other time? What are you entering?

Comment: This might explain your issue. Is it reading your newlines? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012268/cin-get-and-omitting-newline-char

Comment: Are you hitting enter on a system that uses '\r\n' as it's newline deliminator?

Comment: My guess is each time he enters a number/letter and then hits enter.  @KitsuneYMG: That's irrelevent unless he reopened `std::cin` in binary mode.

Comment: @MooingDuck derp. There's a good reason I stay far away from iostream. Give me cstdio anyday.

Comment: Presumably, `cin` is still connected to the keyboard. What are you typing?

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: That makes no sense, cstdio and iostream are exactly the same in that respect.  `freopen(null, "rb", stdin);`

Comment: @MooingDuck more referring to familiarity with the libraries than specific examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin.get()` doesn't get the `'\n'` you typed~

try to use,

```
string str;
getline(cin, str)
```

instead of `cin.get()`

or add a `getchar()` after `cin.get()`

Comment: getline(cin, str) Worked Perfectly! I had to add #include <string>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows:

```
#include <conio.h>

// .. your other stuff

_getch();
```

`cin.get()` is going to grab whatever is in the input buffer (and if you pressed enter, or space, or pretty much breathed on the keyboard, it will have something), or the `EOF` if there is nothing, so it will always return.